# Is it possible loading a different code of html in the same division? Based on anchors clicked

Tags: ajax

I mean without requiring to refresh the whole page, Is it possible to load a part of html code through Ajax into the same division.

eg. If the user clicks on the PROFILE anchor (not having href) the anchor should generate request-object and load the content corresponding to PROFILE in the division below it??

Similarly if he clicks SETTINGS it should load settings details in the same division which was used to load the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. After you do the ajax call, once you get the response, you can bind it to the div. For this set some *id* to the div, do the document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'Your html response'.

Try exploring [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup I've already the code woth ajax and asp.I mean for the profile I've written the code and its running great but the file through to which ajax gives a call also remains directly accessible (I mean directly accessible after typing in the address in the url.) I wish to disable this direct access. And make the file only accessible through Ajax thats where i've got stuck.